# Usage of "tenebrous"

Tags: word-usage

Can the word *tenebrous* be used to mean *ambiguous*?

> Your statement is ambiguous.
>
> Your statement is **tenebrous**.

Comment: You could.  But I wouldn't. If you are arguing ambiguity, tenebrous is certainly not the word to use.

Comment: You can but it wouldn't make sense without a lot of context. your use of 'tenebrous' could only be metaphorical, and it would imply 'difficult to understand' which is not the same as 'ambiguous'. Are you trying for 'unclear'? 'vague'? 'underspecified'?

Comment: What dictionaries led you to think this?

Comment: If you want a metaphorical synonym for *ambiguous*, you should use *cloudy*. People won't understand what you mean if you use *tenebrous*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*Tenebrous*" mostly means obscurity or darkness. Thus it implies [lack of clarity of expression](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ambiguous).

On the other hand, "*ambiguous*" usually indicates the presence of two or more meanings.

To answer your question, yes, "*tenebrous*" can be used instead, but it wouldn't be very  accurate.

Comment: I wouldn't use it. If something is *ambiguous*, I wont say it's *shadowy*, unless we are talking of *Orcus*:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orcus_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)

Comment: I think you mean "obscure or dark," not "obscurity or darkness." *Tenebrous* is an adjective, after all.

Answer (score 2):

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tenebrous) offers as one of the definitions of tenebrous:

*hard to understand: obscure*

I find the metaphorical reference to *darkness* appealing.